# Is this valid XML?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2008

ns1:UserName xmlns:ns1="urn:xxx:remtp:schemas:appxxxTypes:1.00">xxxx</UserName> is it valid xml? 
If so, can we write this line using xml writer? I'm using VS2008. What confuses me is it starts with ns1 and end with `</username>` thanks

Answer (score 2):

No- I don't think you could omit the namespace from the closing tag - it is declared for the content of that tag, but the closing tag is not it's content.

In the tree, the NS appies to it's children only.

Answer (score 1):

According to me it is invalid.

```
<ns1:UserName xmlns:ns1="urn:xxx:remtp:schemas:appxxxTypes:1.00">xxxx</ns1:UserName>
```

would be the correct syntax.

Comment: More importantly, according the the XML standard the STag and ETag's NAMEs must be identical.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, check it out using [XML validator](http://validator.w3.org/) (click on "Validate by direct input").

The validator spits out 2 errors and 4 warnings.

Some of the problems:

- no XML declaration (`<?xml version="1.0"?>`)
- `ns1` namespace not declared and not used for closing `UserName`